# How to report a Bug in a program that does not know the name?

Tags: 12.04, bug-reporting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Every time I start Ubuntu I get a report that some program crashed but it does not show me which are they. How can i know which program is causing the problem.

The dialog box has the text "A program crashed".

```
option --CANCEL ---Report bug.
```

Comment: Welcome you here! Did you run "update manager"? If not, run and install what it shows.

Comment: ya thanks for the welcome i did update and upgrade from terminal and i also ran update manager it shows no updates.

Comment: If you select report bug, you may get more data.  I know I do.

Comment: are you sure you are running as root? try to run `sudo nano /etc/default/apport` to enable apport permanently

Comment: it is enabled already

Comment: guys Some help!

Comment: When I get that message it has an option to see more details. I click it and it takes a minute to think about it. Then it brings up a bunch of information, including the program that crashed and a reason.